# Validar Primeiro dia útil do mês em Python

Tags: python, data, datetime

Preciso que meu código valide o primeiro dia útil de cada mês.

Se hoje é o primeiro dia útil do mês, retorna o primeiro dia do mês anterior, senão retorna o primeiro dia do mês atual.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime

weekday = datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday()
data = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1)

if weekday==1:
    dt = '01/{}/{}'.format(data.month -1, data.year)

else:
    dt = '01/{}/{}'.format(data.month, data.year)

print(dt)
```

Comment: Perfeito. se hoje for o primeiro dia útil, então o resultado deve ser "01/10/2021", senão ele deve ser "01/11/2021".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia básica é:

- se o mês começa em um sábado, então o primeiro dia útil é a segunda-feira dia 3
- se o mês começa em um domingo, então o primeiro dia útil é a segunda-feira dia 2
- se começa em uma segunda, o primeiro dia útil é 1
- se começa em uma terça, quarta, quinta ou sexta, o dia só pode ser 1

Traduzindo para Python:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

hoje = datetime.today()
data = datetime(hoje.year, hoje.month, 1) # dia 1 do mês atual

dia_da_semana = hoje.weekday() # 0=segunda, 1=terça, etc
dia = hoje.day

# se hoje é segunda e é dia 1, 2 ou 3
# ou se é terça, quarta, quinta ou sexta, e é dia 1
if (dia_da_semana == 0 and dia in (1, 2, 3)) or (dia_da_semana in (1, 2, 3, 4) and dia == 1):
    # hoje é o primeiro dia útil do mês
    # muda a data para o mês anterior, primeiro subtrai 1 dia, caindo no último dia do mês anterior
    # e troca o dia por 1
    data = (data - timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)

dt = data.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(dt)
```

Depois, para subtrair 1 mês, eu primeiro subtraio 1 dia (e como a `data` foi inicialmente criada no dia 1 do mês atual, ao subtrair 1 dia ela cai no mês anterior). Depois, basta trocar o dia por 1.

Por fim, uso [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) para formatar a data.
Você estava subtraindo 1 do mês, o que até pode funcionar em muitos casos, mas vai falhar quando o mês for janeiro. Já manipulando a data diretamente, ela trata desses casos também.

---

Outra alternativa para subtrair 1 mês é instalar o [módulo `dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta # pip install python-dateutil

hoje = datetime.today()
dia_da_semana = hoje.weekday() # 0=segunda, 1=terça, etc
dia = hoje.day

data = datetime(hoje.year, hoje.month, 1) # dia 1 do mês atual
if (dia_da_semana == 0 and dia in (1, 2, 3)) or (dia_da_semana in (1, 2, 3, 4) and dia == 1):
    # hoje é o primeiro dia útil do mês
    # muda a data para o mês anterior
    data -= relativedelta(months=1)

dt = data.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(dt)
```

Comment: Excelente, era isso que eu precisava.