# Pegar n-ésimo dia útil do mês, considerando finais de semana e feriados

Tags: python, datetime, data, calendar

Gostaria de obter o n-ésimo dia útil em Python, para um dado mês e ano. [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/535590/validar-primeiro-dia-%C3%BAtil-do-m%C3%AAs-em-python) dá uma boa base para implementar a lógica de checar se o um dado dia é dia útil, porém não considera os feriados do Brasil.

Por exemplo, vamos pegar o mês de Abril de 2021: no dia `02/04/2021`, sexta-feira, houve o feriado de Paixão de Cristo. Logo, o primeiro dia útil é `01/04/2021` (quinta-feira), porém o segundo dia útil é `05/04/2021` (a segunda-feira após o feriado).

Existe alguma forma de automatizar a obtenção do n-ésimo dia útil, considerando não só os finais de semana, mas também os feriados brasileiros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos usar o [pacote](https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays) `holidays` para determinar os dias que são considerados feriados. O pacote tem suporte para o Brasil, inclusive com suporte para feriados estaduais. A partir daí, para um dado mês e ano, podemos construir uma lista de dias úteis e pegar o n-ésimo elemento dessa lista.

Para construir a lista, podemos usar a seguinte lógica:

- Iterar sobre os dias para o dado mês e ano (podemos usar `calendar.monthrange` para obter o número de dias de um mês, inclusive considerando anos bissextos);
- Para cada dia do mês, construir uma data (objeto do tipo `datetime.date`) e avaliar se:

  - A data corresponde a um dia da semana;
  - A data não é feriado.
- Se ambas condições forem verdadeiras, adicionar a data à lista de dias úteis.

A implementação abaixo faz exatamente isso, com alguns ajustes:

- Para melhor usabilidade, o parâmetro `n` foi ajustado para que `n=5` retorne o *quinto* dia útil (elemento de *índice 4* da lista).
- Se `n` for maior que o número de dias úteis do mês, a função retorna `None`.

```
from __future__ import annotations  # para podermos usar | nos type hints

import datetime
import calendar

import holidays


def n_dia_util(
    ano: int,
    mes: int,
    n: int = 1,
    pais: str = "BR",
) -> datetime.date | None:
    """
    Retorna o n-ésimo dia útil para o dado mês e ano,
    considerando os finais de semana e feriados do país.
    Retorna o valor None caso não haja um n-ésimo dia útil 
    para o dado mês e ano. 
    """
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError("O valor de n deve ser >= 1")
    feriados = holidays.country_holidays(pais)
    _, n_dias_no_mes = calendar.monthrange(ano, mes)
    dias_uteis = []
    for dia in range(1, n_dias_no_mes+1):
        data = datetime.date(ano, mes, dia)
        if (
            data.weekday() < 5 and  # data não é sábado/domingo
            data not in feriados    # e também não é feriado
        ):
            dias_uteis.append(data)
    try:
        return dias_uteis[n-1]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Testando a função - note que o segundo dia útil de Abril de 2021 é `2022-04-05` (a segunda-feira após o feriado):

```
ano = 2021
mes = 4
print(n_dia_util(ano, mes, 1))
# output: 2021-04-01

print(n_dia_util(ano, mes, 2))
# output: 2021-04-05

print(n_dia_util(ano, mes, 15))
# output: 2021-04-23

print(n_dia_util(ano, mes, 31))  # não há 31 dias úteis
# output: None
```

Podemos facilmente adaptar a função para retornar dias úteis de outros países (veja a lista disponíveis de países [aqui](https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays#available-countries)), ou até mesmo usar o argumento `subdiv="SP"` para avaliar feriados do estado de São Paulo, por exemplo.